# Shifting data from local android sqlite database to cloud.

Tags: android, sqlite, azure, heroku, cloud

I made an android application which is collecting data from a wearable device and storing it into a local sqlite database.

Now I want to sync the data of all android devices local sqlite databases to cloud and visualize the data and perform data analytics related operations on it.

Can anyone suggest me what to do?

I have looked around multiple clouds like AWS, GAE, AZURE, HEROKU, GoDadddy shared cloud etc for storing my data in a central database.

My question is that should I directly store data from android into mysql or some other database using jdbc or odbc driver or write a webservice or api for storing data in cloud?

I want to sync data after some time interval i.e. a day or so, between local android device and cloud.

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, based on my understanding, you want to sync up the data from wearable device between all android devices and cloud.

Per my experience, the way to directly store data from android into database is not a good choice. The normal way is creating a web service or rest apis to communicate with mobile device for data synchronizing to cloud.

On Azure, the best practice for your needs is that creating an Azure Mobile App instance and enable the `Offline Data Sync` feature in Azure Mobile Apps to implement this. You can refer to the Azure offical document [`Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync) to know the related concept.

You can get start with the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started) for Android within Azure Mobile Apps, and then continous to the next [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-offline-data) to implement the feature of offline sync up data automatically.

As reference, the tutorial [`How to use the Android client library for Mobile Apps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library) will shows you how to use the Android client SDK for Mobile Apps to access the data from SQL Azure table online.

Meanwhile, to visualize the data and perform data analytics related operations on the cloud data, Azure support more [Intelligence + Analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/#pivot=services&panel=analytics) services which could be used for your future plan.

Comment: how about using couchbase mobile which automatically syncs data with couchbase server when user connects to the internet. Because azure is quite expensive and my need for the time being is just to upload local data onto a cloud server. Later I can access this data for data analytics related operations from couchbase server. 
Am I right?

Comment: @BilalZahid It's depended on your choice for technology & cost budget. Make sence that it's a feasible solution to use couchbase mobile for automatically syncing data with couchbase server. If you want to perform this solution and consider for using Azure, you can view the page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/couchbase/couchbase-server-40-community/ to calculate this cost and compare with the cost of using Azure Mobile Apps via using the [Azure price calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).